# org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException for select sql query

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-jdbc

I am getting org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException for select statment. Not sure why spring is trying to put lock for select query.

I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and performing queryforlist. Its all select statements so we are not using and transactions. This database is shared so it might possible there are other application who are writing or performed lock but my app is just read.

This is MS SQL Server.

I am getting exception after 3 secs so looks like spring is trying to get lock and waited for 3 sec and then throws exception.

Below is full exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select id ticketDBId from fpscdb002_ws_004.incident where ticket_number = ?]; Lock request time out period exceeded.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Lock request time out period exceeded.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:259)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForMap(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:238)
    at com.abc.servicedesk.fp.dao.FPBaseDAO.getTicketDbId(FPBaseDAO.java:44)
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57144/in-sql-server-how-do-read-locks-work

Comment: @SeanLange so should I use NOLOCK ??. we are fine with dirty read. Our aim is all data should come from SQL statement which are satisfying where clause.

Comment: Are you really ok with a dirty read? Do you really know what that hint means? In short it means your data will be mostly correct most of the time. It can and will randomly return missing and/or duplicate rows. And it doesn't really mean no locks of any kind. You can read more in depth about that hint and the exciting things it does here. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange so what should be fix to avoid this error. I can't control what other applications are doing.

Comment: You might look into using some isolation levels. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql I can't tell you what is the correct approach here because there are a lot of factors going on in your system.